# Is there anything which is not condensed in nature?

Tags: condensed-matter, definition

Is there anything which is not condensed in nature? In nature we have different kind of matter like solid, liquid and gases and also plasma. Can we consider plasma outside the condensed matter or not?

Answer (score 2):

The references for condensed matter are divided into solid-state physics and soft matter. Open any introductory book on any of those fields and you will see that neither gases nor plasma are considered (unless there is some interaction with a liquid/solid). The only exception to the rule is probably polymers, it may include the study of single molecules (but is a single molecule a gas?).

Of course many books of condensed matter are interested in material behavior that may not behave as solid nor a liquid, and may need to introduce some concepts from gases and plasma. The case of gas-solid/liquid or plasma-solid/liquid interfaces may be treated to provide examples of phase transitions. Gases and plasma may also be treated when discussing the behavior of quasiparticles (holes, excitons,...).

Answer (score 1):

The border between condensed matter and non-condensed matter may slightly change in different communities. Still, from the physical point of view, we can draw a clear separation.

The fingerprint of condensed matter is the presence of interaction and the resulting collective behavior of a piece of material as a whole. Therefore, even gases and plasmas are within condensed matter, while atoms, molecules, and clusters, as isolated systems, are not. Radiation is not within the scope of Condensed matter either due to the independent behavior of photons.